# How can I add a basic splash screen with an image and some text to an existing flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

How can I add a splash screen that contains an image and text widget to this pre-existing project?

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Travel/screens/home_screen.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Safiri',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner : false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF3EBACE),
        accentColor: Color(0xFFD8ECF1),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F5F7),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android you can just change the android manifest to add a splash screen `Android > app > src > main > AndroidMainfets.xml`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <!-- Theme to apply as soon as Flutter begins rendering frames -->
```

then you create a file launch_background (I think it exists when you create a flutter project the first time) in `Android > app > src > main > res > drawable > launch_background.xml`

And it should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
    <item  android:bottom="25dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/myText" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Where splash is an image in your drawable folders (hdpi, mdpi, etc) or you can change it to `@mipmap/ic_launcher` if you want to use the same image as your launcher. The `@color/red` is created in `android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml` where you can define all the colors you want to use as HEX

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#F44336</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="blueGrey">#37474F</color>
    <color name="NightBlue">#233446</color>
    <color name="grey">#212121</color>
    <color name="dark">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

For the text I believe there is no normal way to add text to splash screen, so maybe just create an imagge with a text and do the same as the icon @drawable/myText

For more information about splash screen in flutter check [Flutter Splash Screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem. However I was not able to resize images I added. Images  displayed on the splash screen were overly large.

Comment: Did you make multiple folders and sizes of that images to support different dpi? https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities